# javascript <audio>: cant update currentTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, html5-audio

Im trying to make progress bar for my html5 audioplayer, and make function to change track playing time by tapping. I decided to do it with input[range], but when i tapping on bar current play time doesnt update, track just plays from the start:

my html:

```
<audio controls='controls' class="track">
      <source src="{{ user_lib.audio_file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
      <source src="{{ user_lib.audio_file.url }}" type='audio/ogg; codecs=vorbis' />
      <p>Your user agent does not support the HTML5 Audio element.</p>
</audio>

<div class="progress-bar">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1" class="track-pb"
        onchange="PBtap()" id="track-pb"/>
    </div>
```

my js:

```
function PBtap() {
        $('#track-pb').on('input propertychange', function() {

        var currenttrack = $('.track')[0];
        var val = parseInt($(this).val() * currenttrack.duration / 100, 10)
        $('#track-pb').prop("value", val);
        currenttrack.currentTime = val;
    })
}
```

i tryed to use

```
$(currenttrack).bind('canplay', function() {
            this.currentTime = val;
          });
```

What am i do wrong?

Comment: Can you post your full HTML, including the actual audio element? (Ideally in a codepen or jsfiddle).
You probably don't want `$('#track-pb').on('input propertychange', function() {` within `PBtap()`, but I'm not sure if that will fix your problem.

Comment: i added audio element. Other code not mathing with audio tag. I cant really upload it to jsfiddle or codepen, cause ive got there some django variables, not sure that it will work there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function PBtap(trackpb) {
    var currenttrack = $('.track')[0];
    var val = parseInt($(trackpb).val() * currenttrack.duration / 100, 10)
    currenttrack.currentTime = val;
}
```

And in HTML, change `onchange="PBtap()"` to `onchange="PBtap(this)"`. When onchange is used in this way, `this` cannot be accessed by default.

You can also add the following to change the range value as the audio plays:

```
setInterval(function () {
  var track = $(".track")[0];
  $("#track-pb")[0].value = track.currentTime / track.duration * 100;
}, 100);
```

This will work better if `onchange` is changed to `oninput` in the HTML.

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. I got already setInterval function, but i stopped it, cause i thought that Tap function conflicts with it. But looks like problem is in other thing

Comment: @AndrejVilenskij Look at my codepen: https://codepen.io/z-smith/pen/WayyoO (I used some random audio for demo). It seems to work fine for me (tested in Chrome and Firefox). If it still doesn't work for you, do you get any errors in the console? Note that (in case you haven't tried it yet), using `oninput` instead of `onchange` made a big difference for me.

Comment: Now i just copypasted your code, but its the same. Track just beggining from the start, currentTime value after changing always = 0 (checked it with console log). I changet to oninput, but its still the same. Also i tryed to disable all other js code, but even this doesnt helps yet.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a scope issue. In `$(currenttrack).bind('canplay', function() {`, `currenttrack` is undefined because it is declared in a function.

Additionnally, you use the inline `onchange` to call a function... And that function registers a change handler, jQuery way. It's one or the other.

Try this:

```
var currenttrack = $('.track')[0];
var val = 0;

$('#track-pb').on('input change propertychange', function() {

  val = parseInt($(this).val() * currenttrack.duration / 100, 10)
  $('#track-pb').prop("value", val);
  currenttrack.currentTime = val;
});


currenttrack.on('canplay', function() {
  this.currentTime = val;
});
```

And remove `onchange="PBtap()"` from your markup.

Also... do not use the deprecated `.bind()`. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: well, still doent work. Now track is just stops, when im tapping on progress bar, and i cant run it again until page refresh